# Deleting records using Entity Framework features versus direct use of DELETE stmt

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a many to many relationship between 2 tables.

One of the functionalities consists of deleting all records in navigation table and then repopulate it.

I used Entity Framework, by first deleting related records and then repopulating the collection by mean of this:

```
foreach (var funcionario in listFuncionario)
{
    int fun_id = 0;
    if (!int.TryParse(funcionario.Trim(), out fun_id))
        continue;
    var fun = db.Funcionario.Find(fun_id);
    fun.Servicio.ToList().ForEach(s => db.Servicio.Remove(s));
    fun.Servicio.Clear();
    foreach (var servicio in listServicio)
        fun.Servicio.Add(db.Servicio.Find(servicio));
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Those loops are very slow (specially deletion), however, when I use `ExecuteSqlCommand` to directly issue `DELETE` and `INSERT` statements, the loops are fast.

I don't like issuing SQL commands directly because the essence of Entity Framework and object oriented programming is lost. Do you know any way to do that in a more efficient way using Entity Framework?

Regards,
Jaime

Comment: You could try `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` *before* your outer `foreach` loop which normally improves performance for such kind of bulk operations. Do you really want to delete the `Servicio` entities from the DB (which you are doing with `db.Servicio.Remove(s)`)? Or only the link records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each Id in `listFuncionario` you execute a separate query (`db.Funcionario.Find`). You could speed that up by getting all `Funcionario` records in one shot. You need to parse the Ids first and store them in a `List<int>`, let's say `idList`:

```
var funs = db.Funcionario.Where(f => idList.Contains(f.Id));
```

But you can optimize this further by loading the `Servicio` collections at the same time:

```
var funs = db.Funcionario
             .Include("Servicio") // Or .Include(f => f.Servicio)
             .Where(f => idList.Contains(f.fun_id));
```

now you can do

```
foreach(var fun in funs.ToList())
{
    fun.Servicio.ForEach(s => db.Servicio.Remove(s);
}
```

And you can do the same one-shot lookup for `Servicio` objects to be added, so the final solution is this:

```
var servicio = db.Servicio.Where(s => listServicio.Contains(s.Id)).ToList();

var funs = db.Funcionario
             .Include("Servicio") // Or .Include(f => f.Servicio)
             .Where(f => idList.Contains(f.Id));

foreach(var fun in funs.ToList())
{
    fun.Servicio.ForEach(s => db.Servicio.Remove(s);
    foreach(var serv in servicio)
    {
        fun.Servicio.Add(serv);
    }
}
```

I think the `Clear` of `fun.Servicio` is not necessary.